# HTML lose format when displayed in email

Tags: html, css, email, html-table

I've written a html page which is sent as an email to my email subscribers. The html contains tables and displays grey table borders on my WYSIWYG editor, but loses the border color when sent as an email.

Could you pls help take a look how I can keep the border color? Thanks!

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">.ReadMsgBody { width: 100%; background-color: #ebebeb;}

    .ExternalClass {width: 100%; background-color: #ebebeb;}

    .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height:100%;}

    body {-webkit-text-size-adjust:none; -ms-text-size-adjust:none;}

    body {margin:0; padding:0;}

    table {border-spacing:0; text-align:left;}

    table td {border-collapse:collapse;}
```

part of HTML that contains the table:

```
  <table>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td style="padding: 5px 7px;" valign="top">
  <h3>Ipsum lorem</h3>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td style="padding: 5px 7px;" valign="top">
  <h3>ipsum lorem</h3>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: All email clients don't support CSS classes so you should put all your styles as inline CSS (style="").

Comment: Hi I put the CSS content with <style> tag right above the html code as 1 file in the WYSIWYG editor, is that what you want me to do?

Comment: Here is [a mail chimp article](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-to-code-html-emails/) on writing HTML emails.

Answer (score 1):

All email clients don't support CSS classes so you should put all your styles as inline CSS (style="") to elements.

Usually the WYSIWYG editors displays tables with borders so user can edit the tables easier but you have to specify styles for table by your self outside the editor.

So try adding border to table like:

```
<table border="1" style="border: 1px solid #999">
..
```